# Rails create create default database records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, database

In my application I have an accounts model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invoices
end
```

The `Account` model belongs to the `User` model. After the user is created, some default accounts must be created:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts

  after_create do
    Account.create(name: "Repairs",user: self)
    Account.create(name: "Supplies", user: self)
  end
end
```

Invoices can then be assigned to one of these initial accounts:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accounts
end
```

Is this the proper way to to create the default accounts?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "default accounts"?

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: It seems like an unusual thing to do, and it's still not very clear why you want to do this. And what do you _really_ mean by `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`? We don't like it when foo/bar appear in Code Review questions, because it's a sure sign that you're hiding some information from us.

Comment: I attempted to provide more information. Do you find this useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! you are on right path but we can improve it like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts

  after_save do
    self.accounts.create([{name: "Repairs"}, {name: "Supplies"}])
  end
end
```

Hopefully! This will help.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you explain why this code is better ? Why use after_save instead of after_create ? We don't just post code here, we want to help the Op by explaining things!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `after_save` callback, which only creates those records after saving the object, why not `after_initialize` ([Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts

  after_initialize do
    unless persisted?
      accounts << Account.new(name: 'Repairs', user: self)
      accounts << Account.new(name: 'Supplies', user: self)
    end
  end
end
```

Now the moment you have a new User object, you have default accounts (though unpersisted):

```
@user = User.new

puts @user.accounts[0].name # echoes "Repairs"
puts @user.accounts[1].name # echoes "Supplies"
```

The new accounts will be saved upon saving the user object:

```
@user.save
```